# Ttfidfvectorizer adjust test by training frequencies in pipeline during cross-validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, cross-validation, tfidfvectorizer

I have a text classification task based on documents, where I expect the classes are related to word frequencies.  Because of the specific nature of my application, where I have a corpus that will grow over time and want to classify new documents as they arrive, I have used FeatureHasher rather than the existing TFidfVectorizer (which both vectorizes and does adjustment), since the vocabulary size can grow with new documents.
As discussed here for instance (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154660/tfidfvectorizer-should-it-be-used-on-train-only-or-traintest), it seems correct to me that the term frequencies when doing TFIDF should be calculated relative to the train set only, then used to rescale the test set, rather than first doing rescaling on the entire corpus and then splitting.  This is because using the test dataset for frequency calculations is violating the principle that you shouldn't use this information.
Let's assume you start with a matrix X of raw term frequencies (not adjusted yet) and y, a vector of classes.  The typical order that many code examples show is:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

vec = TfidfTransformer()
#rescale X by its own frequencies, then split
X = vec.fit_transform(X) 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
#...now fit a model
```

but the correct thing should be the following:

```
vec = TfidfTransformer()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
#store rescaling based on X_train frequencies alone
vec.fit(X_train)
#resacale each (transform) by the same model
X_train = vec.transform(X_train)
X_test = vec.transform(X_test)
#...now fit a model
```

Okay, now the main question: I want to conduct some kind of cross-validation, perhaps with GridSearchCV, where I can feed it a set of potential model parameters and conduct several splits of the data for each one.  The typical way to do this is to build a model pipeline and then feed it into the cross-validation utility.  Since pipelines are kind of black boxes that are hard to view the details of, I just wanted to verify whether, if TfidfTransformer is included as a step in the pipeline, that it does the adjustment correctly, as I've mentioned above, by conducting the adjustment on the training data of each split.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. If the tfidf transformer is in the pipeline, it will be fit only on the training set for all the cross validation folds.

Comment: Okay, I mean that was the question.  I didn't think it was obvious, and it's hard to verify anything inside the black box, you have to assume it works properly, and I didn't see anyone mention anything online about it.  But thanks for answering.